# invalid context at is table of cursor_name%rowtype

Tags: database, plsql, db2, procedure, database-administration

..is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703
can you please let me know the issue and clarify me why?
environment: DB2 (oracle compatibility enabled)
the code resembles as:`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body PACK1 IS
    PROCEDURE PROC1 AS 
        CURSOR CUR1 IS SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM TABLE2 ) AND COL3 = 'Y';
        TYPE TYP1 IS TABLE OF CUR1%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; --facing issue here.. please clarify
        ALIAS1 TYP1;
    BEGIN
            ...STATEMENT1..
            OPEN CUR1;
            LOOP 
            FETCH CUR1 BULK COLLECT INTO ALIAS1 LIMIT 1000;
            ...STATEMENTS2...
            EXIT WHEN CUR1%NOTFOUND;
            END LOOP;

            ....STATEMENTS3...
    END PROC1;
END PACK1;`
```

line4 ([provided comment in the line where error is encountered). Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, declare your **TYPE** in package spec

Comment: @hmmftg its not working. can we have any approach to create a temp table in definition and use those temp table as "temp_table%rowtype". This should approach should solve the problem. But donno how to create temp table in procedure declaration section. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

move declaration of your **TYPE** up before procedure declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACK1
IS
   TYPE TYP1 IS TABLE OF CUR1%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   PROCEDURE PROC1
   AS
      CURSOR CUR1
      IS
         SELECT COL1, COL2
           FROM TABLE1
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE2) AND COL3 = 'Y';

      ALIAS1   TYP1;
   BEGIN
      ...STATEMENT1..
      OPEN CUR1;

      LOOP
         FETCH CUR1 BULK COLLECT INTO ALIAS1 LIMIT 1000;

         ...STATEMENTS2...
         EXIT WHEN CUR1%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;
   ....STATEMENTS3...
   END PROC1;
END PACK1;
```

I have faced this issue long ago, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @hmmftg, it resolved the context issue, but now, i am encountering : SQLCODE: -20504, SQLSTATE: 428HS
The statement failed because the target object of the anchored data type is unsupported or is being used in an unsupported context.. SQLCODE=-20504, SQLSTATE=428HS,
Line 6, where procedure statement starts. Could you please help me with this?